# How to open command prompt starting with "shell>" in windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, shell

The Documentation of mySQL explain some issues in command prompt starting with "shell>" command as shown in the picture , while the normal cmd prompt starting with"c:\users\pc>" and the cmd line client of mySQL5.7 starting with "mySql>" ...how to open cmd prompt starting with "shell>"? if not in windows OS what is the correspondent action in windows? .....[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6kCB.jpg)

Comment: Just open a normal windows command windows. Once you run `>mysql -uroot -p` you will get the `mysql>` prompt

Comment: "c:\users\pc>mysql -uroot -p" gave me the response " "mysql" is not recognized " as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file"  @RiggsFolly

Comment: Is this XAMPP or WAMPServer or did you install everything seperately yourself?

Answer (score 3):

"shell>" is a placeholder for whatever your command shell of choice (e.g. bash, cmd.exe, etc.) *actually* uses. It is not literal text.